# Is there any way to make TabBarView.builder in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to make `tabBar` with `tabBarView` but `TabBarView` builds all of its children immediatly. Is there a way to do something like `TabBarView.builder` so every child is built separately?

I have tried with `PageView.builder` but I have to connect it with the tab bar so it didnt help.

Comment: just for some context, why do you want to build all children immediately? I would assume for getting the data?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `List<Tab>` and add some tabs to it. You can also add or remove from the list. Replace the square brackets (`[]`) of `TabBar` and `TabBarView` with the name of the created list which contains your tabs.

### Explanation

If you give a list to the children component, all items will appear and you can change items in real-time

Here is an example code:

```dart
class _MainAppState extends State<MainApp> {
  List<Tab> tabs = [
    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
  ];

  void addTab() {
    setState(() {
      tabs.add(Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'TabBar Demo',
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: tabs.length,
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text('TabBar Demo'),
              bottom: TabBar(
                tabs: tabs,
              ),
            ),
            body: TabBarView(children: tabs),
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: addTab,
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope it helped!